# New BlackBerry text selection mode

Tags: blackberry, java-me, textfield

In recent versions of OS6, text selection has changed.  I am using an [ActiveRichTextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ActiveRichTextField.html) and in BlackBerry OS pre-6.0 as well as older versions of 6.0, such as 6.0.0.246, the focus would move though each character with the inverse block showing current position.   The context menu has "Select" as an option, and uses the current focus position as the selection start, and any focus movement would mark the other end of the selection.

With 6.0.0.526, the focus no longer draws an inverse block on the selected character, and left-right movement on the text field does not work.  Also, the context menu has changed to say "Select Text".   Once this menu item is selected, the behavior is similar to the older OS behavior - the focused character gets an inverse block and left-right movement works.   To start selecting, the context menu now offers "Start Selection" and everything seems to behave as expected at that point.

It seems there is now an extra step to do any text manipulation.  Is there a way to make "Select Text" the default mode for my text field, to match the older behavior?